# Execution order of map[K] = V

Tags: c++, c++11

Give the following C++ code.

```cpp
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> map;
int test = 0;
map[std::make_pair(test, 2)] = ++test;
```

The contents of `map` becomes to `(1,2) -> 1`. Why not `(0, 2) -> 1`？
Can anyone explain the order of execution in this scenario?